# Apply dashboard filter from slice other than Filter Box

Tags: javascript, filter, slice, apache-superset

I want to use a slice other than the Filter Box to apply a filter to my dashboard.

For my dataset, which is structured like a tree, I have adapted the indented tree from the d3 visualizations gallery into a slice that looks something like this:

My tree slice has branches and levels which represent different paths, and end nodes which contain my values.
[image]

Now, I would like to use this slice to filter my dashboard. Particularly, when the user clicks one of my end nodes, I would like to remove any previous values and to apply the value of that node instead.

I have tried representing the path and value of the node as a string and using it like that in the regular Filter Box. However, there are often cases where I end up with really long strings that make for a poor user experience.

I have looked at the Filter Box implementation to see if I could find the method used to change the filter settings. However, this seems to be quite an involved process and re-implementing the Filter Box in my slice seems to me like the wrong approach.

Is there a generic way to change the dashboard filter and apply it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Table" visualization is currently the only other visualization outside than "Filter Box" that's been set up to (optionally) emit dashboard filter events. Here's how it's implemented:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset/assets/visualizations/table.js#L130

The interface for the visualization is a function that receives the `slice` and `payload` params. The `slice` object exposes a `addFiler` and `removeFilter` as shown in the example above.

So it's a matter or setting up your visualization to emit the proper filtering events by using the slice object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using this I was able to solve my issue. Note that any columns you want to filter on need to be in the 'Group By' clause of your custom filter slice. If your column is not in the Group By, applying the filter will fail without any message.